# Regular Expression Nucleotide Search

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a regular expression that will allow me to know if there is a dinucleotide(Two letters) that appears 2 times in a row in my sequence. I give you an example:

Let's suppose I have this sequence (The character `;` is to make clear that I am talking about dinucleotides):

```
"AT;GC;TA;CC;AG;AG;CC;CA;TA;TA"
```

The result I expect is that it matches the pattern `AGAG` and `TATA`.

I have tried this already but it fails because it gives me any pair of dinucleotides, not the same pair :

```
([ATGC]{2}){2}
```

Comment: Why using regular expressions? make a loop where you look `if seq[i:i+n] == seq[i+n:i+2*n]` where n is the length of your pattern (in your case 2)

Comment: I have been asked to do it with regex to practise and I cannot figure out how to do it yet

Comment: Well if it's an exercise to practice and we do it for you, then you don't practice, right?

Comment: hahaahah, it is not my fault this time. It seems that I should be using backreferences when the teacher has not even explained them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use backreferences.

Start with matching one pair:

```
[ATGC]{2}
```

will match any pair of two of the four letters.

You need to put that in capturing parentheses and refer to the contents of the parentheses with `\1`, like so:

```
([ATGC]{2});\1
```

Comment: Thanks that was really useful, I had no notion of backreferences as I am a beginner

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the string were

```
"TA;TA;GC;TA;CC;AG;AG;CC;CA;TA;TA"
 ^^ ^^          ^^ ^^       ^^ ^^
```

If you wish to match `"TA"` twice (and `"AG"` once) you could apply @Andy's solution.

If you wish to match `"TA"` just once, no matter the number of instances of `"TA;TA"` in the string, you could match

```
([ATGC]{2});\1(?!.*\1;\1)
```

and retrieve the contents of capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5cOzSW/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
([ATGC]{2}) # match two characters, each from the character class,
            # and save to capture group 1
;\1         # match ';' followed by the content of capture group 1 
(?!         # begin a negative lookahead
  .*        # match zero or more characters
  \1;\1     # match the content of capture group 1 followed by ';'
            # followed by the content of capture group 1
)           # end negative lookahead
```